# Iterate Windows directories with cygwin

Tags: bash, directory, iteration, cygwin, traversal

I need a shell script to iterate through directories on Windows 10 using cygwin. I am trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="C:\Program Files (x86)"

dirlist=$(find "$path" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
for dir in $dirlist
do
  # Do whatever I want with the directory path.
  echo "$dir"
done
```

But the `for dir in $dirlist` interprets every blank space in Windows directory names as the delimiters. So the result of the above script looks like:

```
C:\Program
Files
(x86)/Mozilla
Firefox
C:\Program
Files
(x86)/Mozilla
Maintenance
Service
C:\Program
Files
(x86)/Mozilla
Thunderbird
C:\Program
Files
(x86)/MSBuild
```

But what I need is this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox
C:\Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Maintenance Service
C:\Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Thunderbird
C:\Program Files (x86)/MSBuild
```

Comment: Does `echo -n "$dir"` helps?

Comment: `echo -n "$dir"` prints all directory names in one line. The "echo" is just a placeholder. I need to do other stuff with each directory. But to do so, I need a full directory name (including blanks) per iteration of the for loop.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' */`, or `dirs=(*/); printf '%s\n' "${dirs[@]%?}"` if you want to remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is not about printing. I need to traverse directory names in general.

Comment: `for dir in */; do echo "$dir"; done`

Comment: Thanks! `*/` works perfect for the current working working directory. Is there also a way to iterate through directories in another path than the current working directory? Or do I have to `cd` into the desired directory before calling `for dir in */; do ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [M. Nejat Aydin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13809001/m-nejat-aydin)'s comment, I am solving it like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="C:\Program Files (x86)"
cpath=$(cygpath -u "$path")

cd "$path"
for dir in */; do
  # Do whatever I want with the directory path.
  echo "$cpath/$dir"
done
```